# Real time prediction of online data using Spark Streaming and Machine Learning

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

How do design an architecture for real time transactional data for classifying as fraud or not?

Random forest classifier ML model is developed, trained and tested using historical data using Scala and Spark MLLib and persisted.

Real time transaction data is getting using Apache Kafka  from one topic and Spark Streaming processed  and writing to another topic for prediction by classifier ML model.

My concern:
How do I provide and get predicted **current transaction data** recieved from Kafka topic using ML Mode mentioned above?

What is best practice for getting predicted **online current single transaction data** using already trained and tested ML model?

Any design suggestions are welcome.

Comment: IMO, you should encapsulate obtained ML model in an object (singleton) and map the upcoming data using this object.

Comment: Thanks @pcejrowski. I created a scala object for model and trained and tested (70:30) with 1000 records. It works!. Now I am missing the link in providing the real time data to this model. Should I provide this as test data agin to model eg. val predictions = model.transform(realTimeData)?

Comment: Yes, I think so :)

Answer (score 1):

You can save the model after training and use it in real time api for prediction. For e.g.,
https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/twitter_classifier/predict.html
Another solution could be to use sparkling-water and use POJO: https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/tree/master/examples#step-by-step-through-weather-data-example

Comment: Thanks@gosanjeev.